# Probelm taking screenshot with selenium py

Tags: python, selenium

My problem is quite simple, i click a button
[image]

I  click on the comment button and I sleep for few seconds to allow the box loading but it remains freezed but if I open the instance browser it shows correctly the box and unforutunately selenium still take a screenshot like this (even if I sleep for more time):
[image]

Comment: How did you code the wait?

Comment: with a simple time.sleep()